Probability of $(A\cup B)$ given $P(A)$ and $P(B)$

A can solve 75% of the problems of Mathematics and B can solve 70%. What is the probability that either A or B can solve a problem chosen at random ?

My attempt at this was to find the range of $$P(A\cup B )$$ which comes out to be $$0.75 \le  P(A\cup B ) \le 1$$
Now as all integral options for the value of the set in this range are equally likely we can use total probability theorem to find the probability.
Following this method I get my answer as 7/8, however the answer given is 37/40. I don't understand where my approach is wrong.
I understand the fault in my approach could be in the assumption that all values for the set are equally likely, but I am unsure how to prove the same.

Is there some information missing? It could be that $B$ is a subset of $A$, in which case $A\cup B=A$. Also, are you asked to give bound on the probability of the union? It is unclear to me from the formulation.

To get the "official" answer of $\frac{37}{40}$, one has to assume independence of the events of A and B getting the right answers on any given problem. This doesn't seem to be a particularly realistic assumption, as some of the problems are likely to be more or less difficult, and then they are more likely to be missed by or gotten by both candidates. Without the assumption of independence, as noted in the original post, the probability could be anywhere between $0.75$ and $1$ (which I think is a better answer than the given answer of $\frac{37}{40}$).

Instead, let's find the probability that neither of A or B can solve the problem:
The probability that A cannot solve a randomly chosen problem is $0.25$ and that B cannot is $0.3$. Thus, the probability that neither can (assuming independence) is just $(0.25)(0.30) = 0.075$.
Therefore, at least one of A or B can solve the problem with probability  $1-0.075 = 0.925 = \frac{37}{40}$.
(Again, though, this assumes that A and B's probabilities are independent -- but since you are not given any information otherwise, this is likely what the asked problem assumes.)
In your approach you are essentially assuming that whenever A cannot solve the problem, B has a 50% chance of solving it.

There's a 0.75 chance that $A$ can solve the problem, and a 0.25 chance that $A$ cannot solve the problem.
There's a 0.7 chance that $B$ can solve the problem, and a 0.25 chance that $B$ cannot solve the problem.
Assuming the liklihood of $A$ and $B$ solving a problem are independant we can calculate the probability of any combination of outcomes:




B solves, $P(B)=0.7$
B does not solve, $P(\lnot B)=0.3$




A solves, $P(A)=0.75$
$0.75\cdot0.7=0.525$
$0.75\cdot0.3=0.225$


A  does not solve, $P(\lnot A)=0.25$
$0.25\cdot0.7=0.175$
$0.25\cdot0.3=0.075$



We then just need to sum the probability of all outcomes where at least one of $A$ or $B$ correctly solves the problem:
$P(A\cup B)=0.525+0.225+0.175=0.925$

They're not uniformly distributed, as typically only $\frac14$ of B's range is outside of A's range, meaning B only gets $17.5\%$ of all questions correct by themselves, and $75+17.5=92.5$, which is the answer.

I don't understand how is B's range only 1/4 outside of A's

Out of 100 questions say, pick 75 that A answers correctly. When you then assign B's correct questions, 3/4 of them will collude with A's, and only 1\4 will be unique to B (on average).
